# Can I add an HTML-style tooltip to a Dojo DataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, dojo, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip to certain cells of a dojo DataGrid, but I don't want to use dojo tooltips. I want to use HTML tooltips so they have a consistent look-and-feel as the tooltips on my buttons.

In a Dojo Tree, there is a tooltip attribute that does exactly this. Is there a way to do this for DataGrids?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to do it with a dojo tooltip? You can style them with your own CSS to make their look consistent.

Comment: @GameWebDev how would you implement that on a cell basis?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by writing a custom format function for the cell.

You need a custom structure object when you create the grid.

May look like this:

```
           var layout = [[{
              name: 'Type',
              field: 'type',
              width: 2,

           },{
              name: 'Name',
              field: 'name',
              width: 'auto',
              defaultValue: '',
              editable: true,
              formatter: dojo.hitch(this, this.formatNameCell)
           }]];
```

Then define a format function for the 'Name' cells:

```
             formatNameCell(name){
                   return "<span title='" + name + "'>" + name + "</span>";
             }
```